# Can a task depend on multiple ShortCircuitOperator tasks in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

For instance, can I set up two shorting-tasks in front of another task:

[short_A, short_B] >> task_A

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

When depending on multiple ShortCircuitOperators, you are essentially creating an AND gate.

So if you want task_A to run, you need `short_A AND short_B AND ...` to `return True`.

If you want to build an OR gate, you either have to replace the shortcircuit operator with a custom one, or raise AirflowSkipException inside normal python operator tasks.

For instance for python tasks A, B and C:

`[A, B] >> C`

You want A and B to implement `raise AirflowSkipException` where you would have set `return False` in the shorting operator. Finally you need to set the parameter
`trigger_rule='none_failed_or_skipped'` on C.